# How to Clean Data in Google Sheet When Have Different Attributes in Each Data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, data-cleaning

I have a data that I must cleaned it by using google sheet. The data that I received is from chat, so when I copy it to google sheet it show like this

| Data |
| --- |
| 13 December 2023, Tender A, n3 (0.5k) dmi : paa 11627, ibp 11560, eup 11400. ACC paa n4 (0.5k) blw : phpo 11627, mm 11565, eup 11400. ACC phpo n5 (0.5k) dmi : ibp 11565, eup 11400, wni 11363. ctr 11627 ACC ibp n6 (1k) tduku : eup 11100, wni 11093, dksd/mpr/sds 6000. ctr 11427 WD |
| 16 December 2023, Tender A, n3 (0.5k) blw : mm 11860, phpo 11801, smart/eup 11600. ctr 11880 ACC m n13 (2k) kalbar : eup 11100, sds/ghsm 6000. ctr 11530 WD |

I want to see price movements based on date. But the problem is for each n in row has different value. The first row start from n3 to n6, but the second row start from n3 to n13.  I think the data should be like this:

| Tender | N | Nominal | Type | Date | paa | ibp | eup | phpo | mm | ibp | wni | ctr | dksd/mpr/sds | ACC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | n3 | 0.5k | dmi | 13 December 2023 | 11627 | 11560 | 11400 |  |  |  |  |  |  | paa |
| A | n4 | 0.5k | blw | 13 December 2023 |  |  | 11400 | 11627 | 11565 |  |  |  |  | phpo |
| A | n5 | 0.5k | dmi | 13 December 2023 |  | 11565 | 11400 |  |  |  | 11363 | 11627 |  | ibp |
| A | n6 | 1k | tkdu | 13 December 2023 |  |  | 11100 |  |  |  | 11093 | 11472 | 6000 | WD |
| A | n3 | 0.5k | blw | 16 December 2023 |  |  | 11600 | 11801 | 11860 |  |  | 11880 |  | mm |
| A | n13 | 2k | kalbar | 16 December 2023 |  |  | 11100 |  |  |  |  | 11530 | 6000 | WD |

If only several data I can do it manually, but I have 1k datas so I don't know what should I do. I also have some sheet that you can try [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f5KIm4vihbNkuMXjNojUnzmbFIGhh-VQZ7dOkHifx4E/edit?usp=sharing). I really apreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Which? Excel or Googlesheets? They are different.

Comment: @SolarMike sorry. I mean google sheet

Comment: What have you tried in terms of formulas or a script?